# String Date Compare

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

In an BDD test I am comparing dates. When Comparing the dates are in strings. Even thought both the dates are same I get this message and the test fails

Expected object to be "01/20/2012 12:00:00 AM", but found "1/20/2012 12:00:00 AM".

One more thing is this happens just on my system. If I ask another developer to run the test, the test passes fine. Is there a setting of some type that I am missing?

The code part of it is

```
            customer["DateOfBirth"].Should().Be(Helper.DateOfBirth.ToString());
```

Where customer is a hash table. this particular statement passes OK on other machines but not mine.

I know I can fix it by changing to date compare instead of String compare. But I was curious, since this is fine on other machines.

Comment: I imagine the problem is with your code. I *have* to imagine, as you have not actually shown us any.

Comment: if the problem is with code, it should not be running fine on another machine correct?

Comment: If you are comparing your dates as strings, then the dates you listed as strings, are not the same.  You should convert to DateTimes then compare.

Comment: @katie77: No, that's not a valid assumption. Your code is probably culture-specific - so will work on computers using one culture by default, but not on others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In an BDD test I am comparing dates. When Comparing the dates are in strings.

That sounds like your problem then. My guess is that you're comparing a date formatted in the default culture to one which has been hand-formatted in some other culture.

The solution is to perform the comparison with `DateTime` values instead, rather than relying on formatted values. Allow the test runner to format *both* values if they're different.

Answer (score 3):

The dates are being formatted differently -- one has a leading 0.

You should either format them the same, or just compare the actual `DateTime` values directly.

Comment: @katie77 it can be, depending on how the date is turned into a string. The best way to compare dates is to use the `DateTime` type.